# Rails: Devise Invalid Auth in SessionController#Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My sign in credentials are working correctly, but whenever I have to sign out from the app, it returns this error exception:

```
 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#destroy

 {"_method"=>"delete"}
```

Does anyone have this solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure devise to allow sign-outs with the http `get` method instead of the `delete` method.

Add this line to your `devise.rb` file.

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Let me know if this solves this